# JVM Performance differences on different Operating Systems

Tags: java, performance, jvm

We were forced to run a performance test on our JVM inside a windows server box. While everything looked good, The application when deployed will be running on AIX.

I understand java is relatively OS ignorant, but in the past I have noticed issues in other applications such as file descriptor limits on AIX.

Is our test valid? Are there any major concerns or areas we should look at closer to determine if we may have an issue.

Comment: _You haven't tested if you haven't tested in a production setting._ I've always found that sound advice.

Comment: Couldn't Agree more with Wivani - something inevitably goes wrong. And there isn't anything you can do but spend time troubleshooting in front of the client (if you have a client - I am assuming you do since it sounds like you don't have access to the box).

Comment: While that's surely the best approach, you can hardly expect the client to give them access to the box months before the final deployment and finding out of performance problems after deployment isn't such a great situation. I'd agree if we were talking about some linux distro, but getting your hands on AIX and a machine that can run it, isn't that simple.

Comment: Test on linux at least it's a UNIX thing. FileDescriptors and sockets (and NIO) are significantly different on windows and linux. Also: thread priorities are different on linux and windows (dunno about AIX, but I expect the linux priority model). Thread priorities are important since mutator threads have to compete w/ the GC and the compiler ones for CPU.

Comment: If you are testing your application occasionally on an identical machine you can still do most of your development on a completely different machine.  Differences can appear, but they don't occur that often.  Perhaps you can use an AIX box for continuous integration (even an old one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you'd run your performance tests on as similar an environment as possible to your production environment. That means CPU, memory, JVM supplier and version, disk setup, network, and so on.

That's the ideal situation. However, if you are running identical JVM versions from identical JVM suppliers, with the same memory, and the same memory tuning parameters, you'll be relatively fine.

I suspect on the AIX box you'll need to run IBM's JVM. You should use IBM's JVM on Windows too.

Comment: +1 for the same JVM aspect. That should certainly have quite some impact and is much simpler than finding an IBM box + machine.

Answer (score 0):

Your company should have different test environments:

- for integration or acceptance
- for pre-production

In a perfect world, the integration or acceptance facilities should similar to those of production (OS wise). 
The pre-production should be a clone of the production and could take over the production in case of a disaster.

Testing and making an application stable is an ongoing process and like **Wivan** said production is just another testing environment.